# Android app crashes after obfuscation, also obfuscated logs received in debug build

Tags: android, crash, proguard, obfuscation

I am working on an Android app, that is in SIT testing phase. My idea is to release a debug obfuscated build to the testing team. For this I have added this piece of code in my build.gradle

```
buildTypes {
        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
            debuggable true
            shrinkResources true
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                    'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
}
```

After this my apk file gets reduced and I am happy with this. But when I run the app and I make a service call, the app crashes.

More bad news is I am unable to read any logs as the logs are in this format -

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method f.f.b.i.b, parameter errorType
        at .a.f$a.<init>(Unknown Source:2)
        at .a.h.c.a(:38)
        at j.l.run(:83)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

What I have noticed is when I put -dontobfuscate command in my proguard rules it works fine otherwise it crashes bad. I am even able to spot my mapping.txt file but I am unaware as to how can I decode the file and read the logs.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: did you write proguard rules

Comment: Yes I have written and removed, in either scenarios I have seen it is crashing, only if I write -dontobfuscate it does not crash.

Answer (score 0):

This might have to do with you using Retrofit and Gson for Serialization.
Try adding this line to your Proguard Configuration.

```
-keepclassmembers,allowobfuscation class * {
  @com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName <fields>;
}
```